# I want to make a button that send me to the bottom of the page

Tags: reactjs

Can somebody tell me how to make a button and when I clicked it to send me to the bottom of the page with REACT.JS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window.scrollTo method [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight
  window.scrollTo(0, windowHeight)
}

<button onClick={scrollToBottom}>Scroll</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is mostly related to Javascript, you can add this function to your React's component.

You can give it a try here

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-qzkynv?file=/index.js

```
goToBottom() {
   window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

The button can be styled by CSS

```
<button onClick={goToBottom}>Go to the bottom</button>
```

To have smooth scrolling, you can add this to your global styles

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```